# Chrome is not maximizing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using this code to maximize but it is not working:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 3):

Not to worry, try the following code

```
driver().manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maximize it by entering the screen-size.
For example:

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
```